# React MobX observables keep resetting

Tags: reactjs, react-router, mobx

I am facing a issue where my MobX store observables keep resetting on route navigation/component load. The scenario is as follows, a user selects an account and stores that in `selectedAccount` observable.

`selectedAccount` will be parsed to a protection component which checks if an account has been selected or not. If not the user has to select an account and will be redirected to a welcome page which is using the protection component. But on navigation `selectedAccount` is reset to an empty object and hence the protection component redirects back to the select account page.

I am wondering if it has something to do with the initialization of the store that holdes `selectedAccount`:

```
export interface IUserStore {
users: any;
singleUser: any;
selectedAccount: any;
getUsers(): Promise<void>;
createUser(obj: any): any;
selectAccount(obj: any): any;
getSingleUser(id: string): Promise<void>;
updateUser(obj: any): any;
```

}

```
export class UserStore implements IUserStore {
@observable users: any = [];
@observable singleUser: any = {};
@observable selectedAccount: any = {};
@observable state = "pending"; // "pending" / "done" / "error"
```

Protection Component:

```
interface AppProps extends RouteProps {
userStore: IUserStore
```

}

```
@inject('userStore')
@observer
export class AccountRequired extends Route<any> {
public render() {

    if (Object.keys(this.props.userStore.selectedAccount).length == 0) {
        const renderComponent = () => (<Redirect to={{pathname: "/selectAccount"}}/>);
        return <Route {...this.props} component={renderComponent} render={undefined}/>;
    } else {
        return <Route {...this.props}/>;
    }
  }
}
```

export default AccountRequired;

It seems like the observables is getting initialized as an empty object every time I load component which uses the store.

What I am missing?

**Update:**

Here is where I inlcude the provider. index.tsx:

```
// Stores
import { stores  } from './Stores';

ReactDOM.render(<Provider {...stores }><App /></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

All stores are export here. Stores/index:

```
import { AccountStore } from "./AccountStore";
import { UserStore } from "./UserStore";
import { RolesStore } from "./RoleStore";

interface Stores {
  [key: string]: any;
 }

export const stores:Stores = {
   accountStore: new AccountStore(),
   userStore: new UserStore(),
   rolesStore: new RolesStore()
}
```

Comment: Could you include your component that renders the `Provider` and the code that initializes the `userStore` in the question?

Comment: Yes, I have updated op. The userStore is injected in multiple places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out i wasn't using `Link` to redirect, I was using anchor tags.

So replacing the anchor tags with `react-router` `Link` solved the issue.

For anyone else running into the same kind of problem, `mobx-persist`is a library that can keep the obeservables value on page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

From [Mobx docs](https://mobx.js.org/best/pitfalls.html):

> MobX observable objects do not detect or react to property assignments that weren't declared observable before. So MobX observable objects act as records with predefined keys.

You can try one of the followings:

- upgrade to Mobx `v5`
- use [observable.map](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/map.html) instead of `observable`
- update/add `selectedAccount` by [selectedAccount.set(key, value)](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/object-api.html)